# How to hover span content from li

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a simple html code that has some data but the li has image background and on hover i want to show the data from span.

HTML CODE:

```
<ul class="container">
<li class="icons_27"><span class="data_27">DATA 27 - TORONTO</span></li>
<li class="icons_28"><span class="data_28">DATA 28 - NEW YORK</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.container li span {
    display: none;
}
.container li span:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

My question is how can i show the span data on hover ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to style the `hover` on `li`

```
.container li:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

but this will work only if your `li` is visible even when the inner span has `display: none`
(otherwise your `li` have no a visible area in which you can hover).

You may solve this potential issue defining, for example, a `width` or an `height` to your list-items.
Or — instead of giving `display: none` to the inner `span` —  you may use a different style, e.g.

```
.container li span {
    visibility: hidden; /* or also opacity : 0; */
}

.container li:hover span {
    visibility: visible;  /* or also opacity : 1; */
}
```

---

Note: the opacity approach (instead of display or visibility) would also give you the opportunity to make a graceful appearing/disappearing effect using a CSS3 transition

Comment: Apparently, the visibility or opacity is not necessary, see the demo I posted http://jsfiddle.net/D3QNr/

Comment: indeed for a list, but it would depends only on this specific markup. if you use instead an inline element (e.g. a `<strong>` instead of `<li>`) the problem would be immediately visible, that's why I said "potential" issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `span` to display when the `li` is hovered, put the `:hover` selector on the `li` instead:

```
.container li span {
    display: none;
}
.container li:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/D3QNr/